# Passing the Canada-USA border with the car of a friend

Tags: usa, canada, borders, automobiles

I am a Swiss citizen living in Vancouver, BC, Canada as a temporary resident (student visa). I am planning a small trip toward the USA and a friend of mine offered me to use her car for this trip. This friend is American (living in Vancouver, BC, Canada) and her car has an American license plate (insured with Liberty Mutual).

Someone told me that, as a non-Canadian, non-American, I might have a hard time crossing the border with a car with US plates. Should I be worried of being rejected at the border? Do I need to prepare some specific documents? Would it help if my name was added on the insurance contract (I don't know if this is possible). My son (7 weeks old) is Canadian. Does it make any difference if he is in the car?

Comment: In theory this should be possible, but the fact that the friend resides in Canada and has a car with US plates seems suspect.  Is the friend a student as well?

Comment: Yes, she is a student too. It is pretty common among my fellow US students to own cars with US license plates. I don't know the details behind that practice. In her case, she arrived in Canada only recently (I don't know when exactly).

Comment: It's probably okay for a student to retain his or her US license and registration.  Certainly most US states allow students from other states to do so.

Comment: What about insurance? is your name on it?

Comment: @JonathanReez many policies allow the insured to loan the car occasionally.  The friend should definitely check her policy.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that I'd be able to close the question singlehandedly.  If the other question does not address your concerns, please advise, and we can reopen this one.